# Assign class level attribute to base class and it should be assigned to all derived classes too

Tags: c#, attributes

I have a custom attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
    public sealed  class CustomAttribute: Attribute
    {
        public CustomAttribute()
        {
        }
    }
```

which I am using in many classes like

```
[CustomAttribute]
    public class ClassOne: MyBaseClass
    {
     .
     .
```

so I have many classes which are derived from **MyBaseClass** and there will be many changes if I want to add this attribute in all the classes.
what I want is that I add this attribute to my base class and all derived class should also have the same attribute assigned to them.

like

```
[CustomAttribute]
    public class MyBaseClass
    {
     .
     .
```

but this doesn't solve the problem, my child classes still do not have the attribute added.
is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: If you want every class that derives form `MyBaseClass` to inherit this attribute then do you really need the atribute? After all, they all inherit from the same class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `[AttributeUsage(Inherited = true)]` property in your attribute.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class CustomAttribute : Attribute {
    public CustomAttribute() {
    }
}
```

But its default value is already true and the derived class should be available for your custom attribute. I recommend example block below for to ensure.

First, define the attributes.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method |
                AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class InheritedAttribute : Attribute { }

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method |
                AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field,
    Inherited = false)]
public class NotInheritedAttribute : Attribute { }

[InheritedAttribute]
public class BaseA {
    [InheritedAttribute]
    public virtual void MethodA() { }
}

public class DerivedA : BaseA {
    public override void MethodA() { }
}

[NotInheritedAttribute]
public class BaseB {
    [NotInheritedAttribute]
    public virtual void MethodB() { }
}

public class DerivedB : BaseB {
    public override void MethodB() { }
}
```

Then, check the attributes.

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Type typeA = typeof(DerivedA);
        Console.WriteLine($"DerivedA has Inherited attribute: {typeA.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(InheritedAttribute), true).Length > 0}");
        MethodInfo memberA = typeA.GetMethod(nameof(DerivedA.MethodA));
        Console.WriteLine($"DerivedA.MemberA has Inherited attribute: {memberA.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(InheritedAttribute), true).Length > 0}\n");

        Type typeB = typeof(DerivedB);
        Console.WriteLine($"DerivedB has NotInherited attribute: {typeB.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(NotInheritedAttribute), true).Length > 0}");
        MethodInfo memberB = typeB.GetMethod(nameof(DerivedB.MethodB));
        Console.WriteLine($"DerivedB.MemberB has NotInherited attribute: {memberB.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(NotInheritedAttribute), true).Length > 0}");

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

[AttributeUsageAttribute.Inherited Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.attributeusageattribute.inherited?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 1):

The question is how are you using that attribute? Because if you have this situation:

```
 [Custom]
 public class BaseClass {}

 public class AClass : BaseClass {}
```

and you do

```
 CustomAttribute ca = typeof(AClass).GetCustomAttributes(true).FirstOrDefault(x => x is CustomAttribute) as CustomAttribute;
```

ca is not null

Answer (score 1):

Both the solutions worked for me - @ddfra and @gurkan .

I've edited my code like this to get the attributes list, and it works too.

```
var attributesList = GetType().GetCustomAttributes<CustomAttribute>(inherit: true);
```